# Does trino（presto） have any caching mechanism?

Tags: presto, trino

I did an experiment on trino370+hive where data was placed in an hdfs cluster in parquet format. I ran the same query twice, the first time using 4s and the second time using only 0.8s. I wonder where this difference comes from, is it because trino has some kind of caching mechanism? If so, how do you turn it off?

I think if trino had no caching mechanism, the execution time would have been similar.